# Changing only a part of a shorthand property

Tags: css

I would like to style the clicked element of the menu.
Here I have 3 menu links, and they each have a different image background and the same linear-gradient.

```
#items-category-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/items-category.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229,217,187,1) 0%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}
#logout-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/logout.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229,217,187,1) 0%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}
#wheel-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/wheel.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(214,195,138,1) 0%, rgba(229,217,187,1) 50%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}
```

The thing is : I would like to change only the linear-gradient when clicked.

So with Javascript, when link is clicked, the class `user-panel-item-selected` is added.

How can I replace the old gradient with the new gradient without deleting the background-image ?
I tried this :

```
.user-panel-item-selected{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(213,180,92,1) 0%, rgba(228,209,156,1) 50%, rgba(213,180,92,1) 100%) !important;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even if you specify only `background-image`, CSS is not expressive-enough to permit you to add or subtract a single `background-image` layer: you have to repeat the entire property value.

Comment: You're confusing shorthand properties (like `background:`) with collection-properties (multi-value properties) (like `background-image`). While `background-image` is a longhand property included in `background`, the fact you can override individual longhand properties is unrelated to the fact you cannot override a single item in a collection-property. This is a limitation of CSS that we can't expect to be fixed for at least a decade at this rate...

Comment: Alright, thanks and sorry for my confusion! I presume it is the same thing if I try changing the gradient layer with Javascript ?

Comment: Correct. JavaScript's CSSOM exposes the `backgroundImage` property as a single `string` value, but at least with JavaScript you can use string-operations to transform the property value rather than blindly overwriting it.

Comment: A solution could be to use pseudo element ::after or ::before for a part of your background

Answer (score 0):

This Snippet here might help. Saves the url via regex and then adds your new gradient and finally sets the style.

```js
function changeGrad() {
 let div = document.getElementById("logout-link");
 let backgroundImageUrl = getComputedStyle(div).backgroundImage.match(/url\(([^)]+)\)/i);
 if (backgroundImageUrl.length > 0) {
 div.style.backgroundImage = backgroundImageUrl[0] + ", linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(213,180,92,1) 0%, rgba(228,209,156,1) 50%, rgba(213,180,92,1) 100%)"
 }
}
```

```css
#items-category-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/items-category.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229,217,187,1) 0%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}
#logout-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/logout.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229,217,187,1) 0%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}
#wheel-link{
    background: url("assets/user-panel/wheel.png") no-repeat 9px center, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(214,195,138,1) 0%, rgba(229,217,187,1) 50%, rgba(214,195,138,1) 100%);
}

div {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="items-category-link"></div>
<div id="logout-link"></div>
<div id="wheel-link"></div>
<button onclick="changeGrad()">Change LG of Logout Link</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, glad I could help - could you mark this as accepted answer? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-element after or before to simulate multiple backgrounds and make it easier to change only one of them.

```css
nav > a{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, green);
}

nav > a:hover{
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

nav > a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/40') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
  <a href='#'></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS variables:

```css
#items-category-link {
  background:
    url("assets/user-panel/items-category.png") no-repeat 9px center,
    var(--c, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229, 217, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(214, 195, 138, 1) 100%));
}

#logout-link {
  background: 
    url("assets/user-panel/logout.png") no-repeat 9px center, 
    var(--c, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229, 217, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(214, 195, 138, 1) 100%));
}

#wheel-link {
  background: 
    url("assets/user-panel/wheel.png") no-repeat 9px center, 
    var(--c, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(229, 217, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(214, 195, 138, 1) 100%));
}

.user-panel-item-selected {
  --c: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(213, 180, 92, 1) 0%, rgba(228, 209, 156, 1) 50%, rgba(213, 180, 92, 1) 100%);
}
```